# How to get a class object with class member in the class object

Tags: c#

In Unix, there is the macro `container_of` which allows to retrieve a reference to a container structure if we have a reference to one of its members. Is there an equivalent way to do this in C#?

For example, if I have a class `Test` with a member I know of, `head`, is there a way to directly get a reference to the containing `Test` instance from a reference to `head`?

I saw the reflection, but I think it doesn't work:

```
public class Test{
    public int a;
    public LinkedList<int>  head;
}

static void main(string[] args)
{
    Test t = new Test(){
       a = 0,
       head = new LinkedList<int>(),
    };

    var myHead = t.head; // how can I get "t" from here?
}
```

Comment: yes using System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>

Comment: I don't understand the question, you want to access to the object t by 1 element in t.head?

Comment: What is the use case for something like this?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here, what are you trying to achieve? Forget about pointers and all that stuff, what is your goal?

Comment: Please read here to learn how you ask better https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you only got your object that's referenced by your member `head`, there's no way to determine where you got it from (from a member in an object named `Test`).

Comment: You can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if you don't implement it by yourself.

In C#, the object references are "one-way". Having a reference, you can access the object it points to. But having the object, you cannot access a reference to it that is stored somewhere - simply because there might be thousands of references to the same object spread across the `AppDomain` and even beyond its borders.

An object of the `Test` class holds a reference to a `LinkedList<int>` instance, that reference is stored in the `head` field. But nothing prevents you from storing the same reference somewhere else.

Consider this code:

```
var list = new LinkedList<int>();

var test1 = new Test
{
    head = list
};

var test2 = new Test
{
    head = list
};
```

Now, the `LinkedList<int>` instance is referenced both in the objects `test1` and `test2`. What "parent" would you expect to reach from that object? See, that doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nearest thing you can do to have the parent of a property:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.AddChild();
        Parent childParent = parent.Children[0].Parent;
        parent.AddChild();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public void AddChild()
    {
        Children.Add(new Child(this));
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

If you debug, you will see both the parent instances refer to the same object and both's children counts get updated